# Match or look up

Tags: excel, format, conditional-statements

I need to highlight cell `J8` *green* only if range `e8:h8`
**Contains a match**. Then I need to highlight cell `k8` *yellow* if the same range `e8:h8` contains a match and so forth `l8` and `m8`

How can I do this using `conditional formatting`? I assume if I can get one done then I can drag down to apply this to numerous sheets I have. All help is welcome and appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Did you forget a tag in your question? Like "excel" or something? It's not clear what "cells" you are talking about.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and describe what you've done so far. Add your code as a [mcve]. You may want to take the [tour].